# tf.nn.softmax does not operate as expected, why?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, softmax

I have built a two-layer encoder-decoder ConvLSTM network and on top of that, I use a convolution layer (number of filters= 1). I feed the convolution layer output into a softmax, but softmax produces all ones which is surprising because when I manually calculate the softmax I get numbers around 0.5.

My convolution layer:

```
def new_weights(shape, name):
    return tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05))

def conv_layer(input,              # The previous layer.
               num_input_channels, # Num. channels in prev. layer.
               filter_size,        # Width and height of each filter.
               num_filters):        # Number of filters.
    filter_shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]
    w = new_weights(shape=filter_shape, name='ConvLayer_Weights')
    conv_output = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                               filter=w,
                               strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                               padding='SAME')

    conv_output = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=3)(conv_output,  training=in_training_mode)


    return conv_output 

pred_1 = conv_layer(input=Conv_inputs,              
                  num_input_channels=num_filters1 + num_filters2, 
                  filter_size=1,        
                  num_filters=1) 

softmax_output = tf.nn.softmax(pred_1)
```

The range I get for the output of the convolution is:

```
min: -0.07310162
mean: -6.542541e-09
max: 0.12119095
```

The range I get for the output of the softmax is:

```
min: 1.0
mean: 1.0
max: 1.0
```

And when I calculate the softmax for the convolution output:

```
calculated softmax for convolution output min: 0.48173272467587763
calculated softmax for convolution output mean: 0.5
calculated softmax for convolution output max: 0.5302607074731537
```

So my question is why Tensorflow softmax produces all ones?

By the way, the shape of the convolution output is (10, 16, 16, 1) and below is the code I use for the calculation of the softmax:

```
softmax = 1/(1+np.exp(-value))
```

Comment: The formula that you mentioned is not softmax. It's a sigmoid .

Comment: That is the formula for sigmoid activation. Softmax takes every node output into account.

Comment: @Sıddık Açıl , you are right but how my model learn when I get all ones as the output of softmax? because in this case, the cross-entropy loss will be all zeros.

Comment: Have you tried `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` built-in function? If so, how did it fare against this problem?

Comment: You cannot use softmax on an axis with only one unit. Softmax normalizes an axis to sum to 1, so if there's only one number it will always be 1. You need to change the activation to `tf.nn.sigmoid` if you want one outbut _between_ 0 and 1.

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl , I tried that and I got zero as the cross-entropy loss function.

Comment: What function did you use to calculate `min,max, mean` for `tf.nn.softmax(pred_1)`? Probably you get `1,1,1` because the output tensor is flattened to 1D array

Comment: @cho_uc , I calculated those statistics on the results I got after running the model.